# ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout: Encoded Signature size doesn't match specified size

Tags: directx11, hlsl, data-structure

I get `[ STATE_CREATION ERROR #161: CREATEINPUTLAYOUT_UNPARSEABLEINPUTSIGNATURE]` with the following code:

```
// Vertex data
struct VertexData {
    XMFLOAT3 v;
    XMFLOAT2 vt;
    XMFLOAT3 vn;
};

// ...

// Create the input layout vertex shader.
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertexLayoutDesc[] =
{
    { "V", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, offsetof(VertexData, v), D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "VT", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, offsetof(VertexData, vt), D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "VN", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, offsetof(VertexData, vn), D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
};

HRESULT hr = g_d3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(vertexLayoutDesc, _countof(vertexLayoutDesc), geomVertexShaderBlob->GetBufferPointer(), geomPixelShaderBlob->GetBufferSize(), &g_d3dInputLayout);
```

And wannabe matching HLSL code:

```
struct Input
{
    float3 v : V;
    float2 vt : VT;
    float3 vn : VN;
};

struct Output
{
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
};

Output main(Input input) {...}
```

I can't spot the mismatch and what exactly the error message is pointing to. Weird thing I have very similar input layout and shaders that work perfectly fine, but this one doesn't.

Comment: please show the arguments to CreateInputLayout

Comment: I am calling `CreateInputLayout()` with the just created vertex shader blob & a `nullptr` input layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is the issue (buffer pointer mismatch - geom**Vertex**ShaderBlob vs geom**Pixel**ShaderBlob):

> `geomVertexShaderBlob->GetBufferPointer(), geomPixelShaderBlob->GetBufferSize()`

Comment: This is exactly what I have written, I don't get it. EDIT Damn!!! I'm really that stupid =)

Comment: @PinkTurtle Updated the answer, do you see it now? :)

Comment: Yus I do :) ....